# Can local variables be instance variables?

Tags: data-structures, java

I know that variables can be categorized in two ways:-

**The first way is to classify them into global and local variables** based on their scope. When the variable is accessible by all the functions of an instance of a class then it is known as a global variable and when it is accessible only within a block of code in an instance of a class it is known as local variable.

**The the second way is to classify them into class/static variable and instance/non-static variable**. Class/static variables are those variables which belong to the class and only one copy of these variables exist for all instances of the class and it is shared by them. Instance local variables are those variables which belong to the instance of the class and for which a separate copy is created for each instance.

My instructor says that instance variables can only be declared outside functions. Why is this so? Can local variables not be instance variables?

Comment: Questions about programming belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: @adrianN I think this belongs more to theory of programming rather than programming.

Comment: @MrAP: for conceptual questions about software development, you can also try [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your instructor is right.

Instance variables refer to to variables that are defined in a class, where **every instantiated object has a separate copy of the variable.** For this to be true, it must be a variable within a class but outside any method- so that it is accessible by every method in the class.

A local variable cannot be an instance variable because of this reason. Local variables must exist in a method, constructor, or some other block.